# Create AWS Lambda function using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I faced with a problem concerning of creation of Lambda function using Terraform. I tried to follow a standard documentation of Terraform to configure it, but in my case it doesn't work. When the Terraform try to create an IAM role for Lambda function I get an error:

"Error: failed creating IAM role ... AccessDenied: User: ... is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateRole on resource: ... because no identity-based policy allows iam:CretaeRole action ..."

Actually, If I correctly understood it requires additional policy for my account or a root privilege, I don't have both and I need to use already existed IAM role. Is there way to configure it in Terraform?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use IAM role with terraform as explaiend in TF docs:

- [Using AWS AssumeRole with the AWS Terraform Provider](https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041289933-Using-AWS-AssumeRole-with-the-AWS-Terraform-Provider)